# Predicting end of month data from current data and potentially past data

Tags: forecasting, small-sample

I want to estimate the value of a quantity at the end of the month.

Currently, we use a very dumb method, which is simply to take the current rate at the current point in the month, get the rate (in quantity/sec) and extrapolate to the end of the month. This is very inaccurate at the beginning of the month.

I was looking at using some form of exponential moving average (I would have scaled the smoothing factor over the month to rely more on the past data at the beginning of the month, and more on the dumb prediction while approaching the end of the month). But it seems that those methods need some past data over a certain period to estimate, but in my case for some customers who signed up recently we potentially not have past data (in this case, we're obviously okay with going our dumb method).

My problem is I'm wondering if there is a way to play with the smoothing factor to account for smaller sample sizes of past data.

Sorry if this is a mess, I can provide clearer details if needed, I'm a mathematician/programmer but I suck at stats.